# What is a residue class?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, definition

My number theory book has hopelessly lost me on the topic of residue classes. I understand the very basics of congruence and modular arithmetic, but if someone could give not only a formal, but intuitive and helpful explanation. Also I need to understand why they matter, or I will likely have difficulty grasping the concept.

Comment: there is a simple tutorial about it http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Residue_Class

Comment: http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~kyle/files/Math%20100-4.1.pdf also this one

Comment: Thank you, that was most instructive, I still don't understand the application however...

Comment: application could be even  scripting technology,i mean  enryption/decryption of message, mathematical it says  that  we can deduce  from complex  class of number to  smaller one with  common characters,like they are all  congruent to some   prime or  another integer

Comment: a modular shift cipher? That makes sense, thanks. Would a clock be similar? (12+1 is 1 on a clock)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Basically residue classes are the possible remainders. For example:

$a \equiv b \ (\mathrm{mod}\ m)$

We say, $b= [a]_m$

Now for the **APPLICATIONS:**

$\implies$ This is used in most of the famous theorems, for example: [Fermat's little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem)

$\implies$ Modular arithmetic is often used to calculate checksums that are used within identifiers - International Bank Account Numbers (IBANs) for example make use of modulo $97$ arithmetic to trap user input errors in bank account numbers.

$\implies$Arithmetic $\mod 7$ is especially important in determining the day of the week in the Gregorian calendar. In particular, Zeller's congruence and the doomsday algorithm make heavy use of $\mod-7$ arithmetic.

And yeah, as you said it is used in clocks, too.

This is just a gist of the applications. Residue classes find applications in **security systems**. You will find more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Applications) .:)

Comment: Yes. I'm here, down voter can explain.:)

Answer (score -1):

I am unable to give an explanation that won't be considered straight up plagiarism, but if you can find Anderson and Feil's book "A First Course in Abstract Algebra" (which for a while I renamed "A First Curse in Abstract Algebra" till I started understanding bits and pieces of it) then I recommend their short chapter on Modular Arithmetic (chapter 3 in the second edition).

I found their explanation - and even their proofs - of residue classes reasonably easy to follow, and it opens up the world of arithmetic on residue classes right away.

Interestingly a preview of that book up till page 33 can be found [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B006PKWCHI) and that just about includes their basic intro to residue classes. The missing part of the chapter is about arithmetic on residue classes - but if you get the first bit then the arithmetic can be understood from wikipedia or other online sources.